# Multiple rows in spite of using outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, multiple-records

I have 2 tables below

```
Paam Table
AssignmentID     PersonID         AssignmentType
300000014199240  300000014199145  E
300000014199174  300000014199145  ET

Par Table
ASGResponsID    AssignmentID    PersonID        Responsibility_Type
300000015244074 300000014199240 300000014199145 RC_HR_BP
300000015242351 300000014199240 300000014199145 RC_HR_BP
300000015244070 300000014199240 300000014199145 RC_HR_BP
```

I want to join these 2 tables and get output like below

```
PersonID         Responsiblity_Type
300000014199145  RC_HR_BP
```

I am using the below query

```
select 
par.PersonID, par.Responsibility_Type 
from 
per_all_assignments_m paam, per_asg_responsibilities par
where
sysdate between nvl(paam.effective_start_date,sysdate) and 
nvl(paam.effective_end_date,sysdate)
and  paam.assignment_type='E'
and paam.assignment_id = par.assignment_id(+)
and paam.person_id = '300000014199145';
```

Instead I am getting output like below

```
PersonID         Responsiblity_Type
300000014199145  RC_HR_BP
300000014199145  RC_HR_BP
300000014199145  RC_HR_BP
```

In spite of using left outer join I am getting multiple rows, why is this happening?

Can someone please help me understand ?

Thanks,
Shivam

Comment: Wow, it's been some time I've last seen this ancient outer join syntax. Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 11

Comment: And the task is exactly what? Show all different responsibility types for person '300000014199145' assignments of type 'E'?

Comment: @shivam: Then use proper ANSI joins (`from a left outer join b on ...`). The join syntax you are using was made redundant with the standard SQL joins.

Comment: I just want to show in output the personId and responsibility_type, since this specific person has single responsibility_type then only 1 row should come in output.

Comment: But what would you show, if, say, the second par row had a different responsibility type? Two rows? Or only one of the two? And why don't you join on personid by the way? Could these be different persons in the two tables for the same assignment? What are the tables unique keys?

Comment: I have hardcoded Reponsibility Type to 'RC_HR_BP' in a outer query which is used here. Since person id is same in all the rows so I though of using assignment_id to join. For same assignment different persons cannot be there in both table, a specific person can have single assignment in both table. The Unique keys are the first column of both the table.

Comment: I don't understand. So the tables are not tables, but query results? Then maybe you should change those queries in order to avoid having the same person and responsibilty type multifold. If these are tables on the other hand, you should change the data model to get rid of the redundancy. And 'RC_HR_BP' is hard-coded? Then why do you need to select it, when you already know it's always 'RC_HR_BP'?

Comment: Learn what left join returns: inner join rows plus unmatched rows extended by nulls. Read the manual re how to use (+): among other things, (+)-free conjuncts are done after the join. The manual also says don't use it, use explicit left join. PS Act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Start by using a regular `join` with proper syntax:

```
select par.PersonID, par.Responsibility_Type 
from per_all_assignments_m paam join
     per_asg_responsibilities par
     on paam.assignment_id = par.assignment_id and
        paam.person_id = par.person_id  -- presumably also needed for the join
where sysdate between nvl(paam.effective_start_date, sysdate) and 
nvl(paam.effective_end_date, sysdate) and
      paam.assignment_type = 'E' and
      paam.person_id = '300000014199145';
```

Your intention with the outer join might be:

```
select par.PersonID, par.Responsibility_Type 
from per_asg_responsibilities par left join
     per_all_assignments_m paam
     on paam.assignment_id = par.assignment_id and
        paam.person_id = par.person_id  and
        sysdate between nvl(paam.effective_start_date, sysdate) and 
nvl(paam.effective_end_date, sysdate) and
        paam.assignment_type = 'E' and
where par.person_id = '300000014199145';
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I have already tried these but still getting same multiple rows. I think I may need to use row_num function

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, you're getting the correct results. All three rows in the par table have the same assignmentId (300000014199240) so will be returned by your query regardless of the join syntax.

Adding a "Distinct" clause will get you the results you want.

```
select DISTINCT
  par.PersonID, par.Responsibility_Type 
from 
  per_all_assignments_m paam, per_asg_responsibilities par
where
  sysdate between nvl(paam.effective_start_date,sysdate) and 
  nvl(paam.effective_end_date,sysdate)
  and  paam.assignment_type='E'
  and paam.assignment_id = par.assignment_id(+)
  and paam.person_id = '300000014199145';
```

I set this up in a SQL Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7b7f/8. Note: I removed the date field references since you didn't give us data for those, but it shouldn't affect the results based on how you described the problem.